# Magento Observer function with External PHP classes error

Tags: php, class, magento, module

I am trying to accomplish something which I think is getting beyond my current PHP skills!
I have **working** code in a Magento .phtml template file that calls an external PHP class e.g.

```
$ExternalLibPath=Mage::getModuleDir('', 'My_Module') . DS . 'lib' . DS .'class.authentication.php';
require_once ($ExternalLibPath);
$myauth = new Authentication();
$credentials = $myauth->get("account_credentials");
echo "Connecting as " . $credentials->user_name ;
```

(In the .phtml file the classes are called from an include). I'm trying to move the code from the frontend template files to a Magento module/extension with a class triggered on an event. My module works fine up until the external classes are accessed where trying to access *$credentials->user_name* causes an Undefined property: stdClass: error.

I don't understand why the code works in a .phtml template and not in the module, or what I am doing wrong!

Any help would be appreciated.

Pete.

Comment: Define what you mean by "not working" (expected behavior vs. actual behavior)  Define what you mean by "in a module", your use of the phrase doesn't jive with common understanding of the term within the Magento Community.

Comment: Expected behaviour - code executes without error as it does when accessed with mysite/authenticate.phtml, actual behaviour PHP exception error!

By "in a module" I mean a magento extension, code created in app/code/local/MY/Module/Model/code.php using PHP classes in app/code/local/MY/Module/lib @Alan Storm

Comment: And what's the error message you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the class directly from the phtml:

$credentials = Mage::getModel('namespace/custom_class')->getAccountCredentials();

and return whatever you need to.

Comment: `Mage::getModule` does not exist.

Comment: sry - getModel, not getModule

Comment: $myauth is an object created from a class, with "get" a function within that class returning account credentials.

Comment: Ok.... What does the get function do? can you call other functions within your class w/o error?